# How to pass a sectionlist sectionHeader's index to the reducer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native, redux

Looking to map items with index using `SectionList`, I was successfully able to map the index of the sections and pass the state to the reducer, however, the section header has a different index and would like to do the same with it. Help me up with some examples if possible. This is something that I am developing for a food tech app which and I want to implement the Cart Functionality in the App.

`SectionList`:

```
<SectionList
      sections={this.props.user.dailyMenuData.item.map(
        ({category, data}, index2) => ({category, data, index2}),
      )}
      keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
      renderItem={this.renderMenu}
      renderSectionHeader={({section: {category, index2}}) => (
        <CText style={styles.headerStyle}>{category}</CText>
      )}
    />
```

The above data is coming from `MongoDB` like below:

```
 DATA = {
    vendor_id: XXXXXX (For Mapping Vendor to the Menu)
    company_id: XXXXX (For Mapping the Customer to the Menu)
    item: [
      {
        category: 'A La Carte',
        data: [
          {
            src:
              'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/01/14/22/fruits-2565817_960_720.jpg',
            name: 'Coffee with Pancakes',
            price: '160',
            rating: 3.8,
            calorie: '130',
          },
      }],
    },
```

The `AddtoCart` Reducer is dynamically getting the value of the index of `data[]` however it is not able to get the index of `item[]` from the API called. The reducer code is given below:

```
case ADDTOCART:
  return update(state, {
    dailyMenuData: {
      item: {
        1: {
          data: {
            [payload.index]: {
              quantity: {
                $set:
                  state.dailyMenuData.item[1].data[payload.index].quantity +
                  1,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
```

Comment: I managed to get it done, however. I am not able to update the state in the reducer. My AddtoCart Reducer has mapped data and it is taking quantity from DB, which I don't want. I used it as a temporary solution

Comment: I managed to get it done again Hurrah!!!. I passed the itemIndex from the sections prop in the SectionList. My code looks like this.

<SectionList>
    sections={this.props.user.menu.item.map(
    ({category,data}, itemIndex) => ({category,data, itemIndex}),
)}
</SectionList>